# Ignore keyup for a few seconds for ux

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a multistep form using jquery validator plugin that also goes to the next page when you press enter.

```
function showPage(pg){
    $('formError').empty();
    $('table:visible').hide();
    $('#page-' + pg).show();
    $('input[type="text"]:visible').focus();
}
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
if(e.which == 13) {
    if($('#msform :input:visible').valid()){
    page++;
    showPage(page);
    }}});
```

The issue is that if you use the enter button, it triggers a validation error on the next page because the button is still being pressed and it tries to go to the next page.

How can I ignore the enter key for a small period so that releasing the enter key works to go to the next page without attempting to go to the page after the next page?

Comment: The wording of your question is quite ambiguous. Explain it in a bit simpler way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wait for the corresponding keyup event before taking in account a new keydown event for the enter key.

```
pressed = {};

$(document).keydown(function(e){
        if(pressed[e.which] == null && e.which == '13'){
            if($('#msform :input:visible').valid()) {
                page++;
                showPage(page);
                }
            }
        pressed[e.which] = true;
});

$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    pressed[e.which] = null;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use setTimeout() function like this

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    setTimeout(myFunction(),500);
    });
function myFunction(){
    if(e.which == 13) {
      if($('#msform :input:visible').valid()){
      page++;
      showPage(page);
    }}
}
```

::::::::::::::::::Update::::::::::::::::::

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
     if(e.which == 13) {   
       setTimeout(myFunction(),500);
     }
  });
function myFunction(){
   if($('#msform :input:visible').valid()){
     page++;
     showPage(page);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Oddly, it posts from the first page when i try this.